# Firebase orderByChild on React Native

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, react-native-firebase

I am  having an issue with ordering of a list on android.  The database ref  items/ looks like  this below:

```
{
    "11" : {
        "date" : "2018-11-18 10:07:00",
        "letter" : "F",
        "number" : 11
    },
    "12" : {
        "date" : "2018-11-01 14:41:00",
        "letter" : "B",
        "number" : 12
    },
    "13" : {
        "date" : "2018-11-13 14:00:00",
        "letter" : "C",
        "number" : 13
    },
    "14" : {
        "date" : "2019-04-22 22:15:30",
        "letter" : "D",
        "number" : 14
    },
    "15" : {
        "date" : "2019-04-22 20:33:00",
        "letter" : "H",
        "number" : 15
    },
    "16" : {
        "date" : "2019-04-22 19:30:00",
        "letter" : "J",
        "number" : 16
    },
    "17" : {
        "date" : "2019-04-25 13:10:00",
        "letter" : "G",
        "number" : 17
    },
    "18" : {
        "date" : "2019-04-25 18:00:00",
        "letter" : "E",
        "number" : 18
    },
    "19" : {
        "date" : "2019-04-25 13:00:00",
        "letter" : "I",
        "number" : 19
    },
    "20" : {
        "date" : "2019-04-28 12:30:00",
        "letter" : "A",
        "number" : 20
    }
}
```

I am querying it as below expecting the results to be ordered  by the 'letter' key:

```
firebase.database().ref('items/').orderByChild('letter').on('value', snapshot => {
    let items = snapshot.val()
    Object.values(items).map(i => console.log(i.number, i.letter, i.date))
})
```

But I get the results logged as  below:

```
11 F 2018-11-18 10:07:00
12 B 2018-11-01 14:41:00
13 C 2018-11-13 14:00:00
14 D 2019-04-22 22:15:30
15 H 2019-04-22 20:33:00
16 J 2019-04-22 19:30:00
17 G 2019-04-25 13:10:00
18 E 2019-04-25 18:00:00
19 I 2019-04-25 13:00:00
20 A 2019-04-28 12:30:00
```

Obviously the orderByChild('letter') is not getting applied. What could I be missing?

Comment: Consider storing your dates as Long (Number is JS)

Comment: Thanks for that. Meanwhile, can you test and confirm the same issue I have?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently there is an issue with how objects are handled in JavaScript, that's why there is a snapshot.forEach method for one to use instead of the Object.values(items).map that I am using. My listener should look something like this:

```
firebase.database().ref('items/').orderByChild('letter').on('value', snapshot => {
    snapshot.forEach(c => { i = c.val(); console.log(i.number, i.letter, i.date) })
})
```

> Because of the way JavaScript objects work, the ordering of data in
>   the JavaScript object returned by val() is not guaranteed to match the
>   ordering on the server nor the ordering of child_added events. That is
>   where forEach() comes in handy. It guarantees the children of a
>   DataSnapshot will be iterated in their query order.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot#forEach